# Accumulation of previous Day values into current date

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to Accumulation values of previous day production+sock to update today date.

I implemented below snippets as working as expected but initial value which has to take very first day then today stock+production = next date so on

```
let prevStock = 20;
let stocksArr= [
  { date: '2021-07-01', stock: 3, production: '5' },
  { date: '2021-07-02', stock: 7, production: '2' },
  { date: '2021-07-03', stock: 6, production: '1' },
  { date: '2021-07-04', stock: -3, production: '5' },
  { date: '2021-07-05', stock: 0, production: '3' },
  { date: '2021-07-06', stock: 10, production: '4' },
  { date: '2021-07-07', stock: 7, production: '1' },
  { date: '2021-07-08', stock: 10, production: '4' }
]

  stocksArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const newArr = acc + cur.stock;
    cur.stock = acc;
    return newArr;
  }, 0);
```

expected results:

```
results= [
  { date: '2021-06-30', stock: 21},
  { date: '2021-07-01', stock: 25},
  { date: '2021-07-02', stock: 30},
  { date: '2021-07-03', stock: 32},
  { date: '2021-07-04', stock: 33},
  { date: '2021-07-05', stock: 38},
  { date: '2021-07-06', stock: 41},
  { date: '2021-07-07', stock: 45},
  { date: '2021-07-08', stock: 56}
]
```

```js
let prevStock = 21;
let stocksArr= [
  { date: '2021-07-01', stock: 3, production: '5' },
  { date: '2021-07-02', stock: 7, production: '2' },
  { date: '2021-07-03', stock: 6, production: '1' },
  { date: '2021-07-04', stock: -3, production: '5' },
  { date: '2021-07-05', stock: 0, production: '3' },
  { date: '2021-07-06', stock: 10, production: '4' },
  { date: '2021-07-07', stock: 7, production: '1' },
  { date: '2021-07-08', stock: 10, production: '4' }
]

  stocksArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const newArr = acc + cur.stock;
    cur.stock = acc;
    return newArr;
  }, 0);
console.log(stocksArr)
```

What is the right approach to resolve it?

Comment: Why would the stock on 2021-06-30 be 21 and not 0, as shown in the first object, `{ date: '2021-06-30', stock: 0, production: '4' },`?

Comment: sum of previous day stock+production I am fetching db and initialed it. so I have previous day stock+production

Comment: @HereticMonkey So based on previous day stock+production has to calculate.

Comment: Well, I would suggest you use that `prevStock` as the initial value for the `reduce` call (the second argument, where you are currently passing 0. Also, you'll need to add production to `newArr` if you want that to be added (I'd convert it to a number, maybe use `parseFloat(cur.production)`, or `parseInt` if those values are always integer values).

Comment: Why do you want to use reduce for this? Also, the data in `stocksArr` and the `result` doesn't seem to make sense, where does the `2021-06-30` come from??

Answer (score 2):

You're quite close; you just need to use the other parameters passed to the `reduce` function.

```js
let prevStock = 21;
let stocksArr = [{
    date: '2021-06-30',
    stock: 0,
    production: '4'
  },
  {
    date: '2021-07-01',
    stock: 3,
    production: '5'
  },
  {
    date: '2021-07-02',
    stock: 7,
    production: '2'
  },
  {
    date: '2021-07-03',
    stock: 6,
    production: '1'
  },
  {
    date: '2021-07-04',
    stock: -3,
    production: '5'
  },
  {
    date: '2021-07-05',
    stock: 0,
    production: '3'
  },
  {
    date: '2021-07-06',
    stock: 10,
    production: '4'
  },
  {
    date: '2021-07-07',
    stock: 7,
    production: '1'
  },
  {
    date: '2021-07-08',
    stock: 10,
    production: '4'
  }
]

stocksArr.reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
  // use parseInt if you know these are always integers
  // if we're on the first line, don't look for a previous object
  // if not, get the previous object's production value
  const prod = idx === 0 ? 0 : parseFloat(arr[idx - 1].production);
  // newArr seemed like an odd name, so I changed it to value
  // Add the previous stock to the current stock, plus the previous day's production
  const value = acc + cur.stock + prod;
  // set the stock
  cur.stock = acc;
  return value;
}, prevStock); // using prevStock for the "initialValue"
console.log(stocksArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with a for loop.

The first element in the array is given prevStock as its stock value and then each iteration of the loop sets the current stock plus the current production to the next element's stock value.

Finally, the production key is deleted from each object to match the expected output.

```js
let prevStock = 21;
let stocksArr= [
  { date: '2021-06-30', stock: 0, production: '4' },
  { date: '2021-07-01', stock: 3, production: '5' },
  { date: '2021-07-02', stock: 7, production: '2' },
  { date: '2021-07-03', stock: 6, production: '1' },
  { date: '2021-07-04', stock: -3, production: '5' },
  { date: '2021-07-05', stock: 0, production: '3' },
  { date: '2021-07-06', stock: 10, production: '4' },
  { date: '2021-07-07', stock: 7, production: '1' },
  { date: '2021-07-08', stock: 10, production: '4' }
]

stocksArr[0].stock = prevStock;
for(var i = 0; i < stocksArr.length-1; i++)
{
  stocksArr[i+1].stock = stocksArr[i].stock + parseInt(stocksArr[i].production);
  delete stocksArr[i].production;
}
delete stocksArr[stocksArr.length-1].production;

console.log(stocksArr);
```

I'm following your output up until the very last entry, where I believe you have a typo in your expected output since one item is produced but the stock is increased by 11 in your example.

Comment: Thanks for Answer. Can use es6 feature to shorten this snippets?

Comment: So you just edited the input data to include the 2021-06-30 ?

Comment: I copied the original snippet. The 2021-06-30 was present in that snippet.